# Wrongly marked as duplicate

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicates

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208410/) that was wrongly  marked as duplicate (has been reopened since) to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/188015/) .

The marked one asks "How can the unstable particles of the standard model be considered particles in their own right if they immediately decay into stable particles?"

and the suggested original "What is the essential difference between a resonance and a particle? "

The answers to the last do not address the problem. The Z and W mesons are more than  resonances, they are elementary particles of the standard model . The  "duplicate" asks if the elementary particles could be excitations .

Two different problems.

Could the moderators have a look?

Edit: question is open with votes. see my comment below

Comment: Agreed, the question has been wrongly closed, though whether this is a task for the moderators is debatable. Isn't it down to the site users to vote to reopen (as I have done)?

Comment: Hi John. I voted to open it too. I just wanted to draw the attention of more people who are familiar with the background of particle physics, and thought this entry might help

Comment: The question has been opened by votes but I am keeping this meta question open as an example of hasty duplicate closure, people not reading in depth the question.

Comment: Phys.SE has currently ~200 3k+ users who potentially could review posts, but in practice it the same handful of users who are doing all the reviewing on Phys.SE. With ~75 new questions arriving every day, mistakes are bound to happen. But that's what the reopen queue is for. This meta post was created only [13 minutes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/timeline/208410) after the first reopen vote was cast. It seems there is no need to create a hall of shame. At least erase the names of the 5 reviewers. Don't make it harder to recruit new reviewers.

Comment: @Qmechanic done. I was probably writing this post while somebody was asking for a reopen

Comment: @Qmechanic Not a hall of shame, what an exaggeration. Just a call to be a bit more careful

Comment: @anna v: Right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just posting so that this doesn't count as unanswered: the question was reopened by the community. (As it should be. This isn't something that really *needs* moderator intervention.)

Comment: Yes, community voting is fine for this, except that sometimes questions disappear from first page very fast . I just posed the question to draw the attention of more people.

Comment: Sure, and that's exactly the right thing to do in such a case. Just saying that the question doesn't need to ask for moderator intervention specifically.